# Is std::vector::clear()-ing an inner vector of a 2-D vector thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, data-race

Let's say I have an object `threadWork` initialised as:

```
vector< vector<myType> > threadWork(N_THREADS, vector<myType>());
```

I then deploy `N_THREADS` threads, each performing writes via `vector::push_back()`s to a separate element (its own `vector<myType>` object) of `threadWork`.

One thread then calls `vector::clear()` on its element of `threadWork`.
Does this invalidate the writes of the other threads to their element?
i.e Can `vector::clear()` called on one element of `threadWork` alter 
the memory allocation of the other elements of `threadWork`,
such that a thread may be writing to invalid addresses as a result?

Comment: If there is no concurrent access to the **same** element, there is no data race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely fine. Altering an element of the outer vector does not affect the other elements in any way.